# Tracking MSMQ Messages through Queues

Tags: msmq

I am trying to track MSMQ messages through nServiceBus through multiple queues.  I see a correlation ID but it doesn't seem to show up in the next queue.

Is there something specific that I should be looking for that I can use to track a messages?  I was parsing the payloads but most of the queues compress the messages so the payloads were opaque.

Is there anything that might identify a message as it traverses the queues?

Thanks!

John

Comment: An MSMQ message is a single-hop package. Once delivered to its destination queue, it's finished moving. A message moving across multiple queues is really multiple single-hop messages. The correlationID only relates to a single hop so you won't see it on the next hop.

Comment: That's what I feared, Thanks John!

Comment: How about getting nServiceBus to apply a Message.AppSpecific property to the message at each hop?